# Calling constructor of superclass doesn't work

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

In the code of a game I'm making, I have a class named `Entity`. This is the superclass of all graphical objects in the game (spaceships, missiles, etc).

`Entity` has an attribute `int type`. `Entity` receives a value for `type` in it's constructor (`public Entity (int type)`).

Class `Ship` extends `Entity`. It needs to have a value in `type`. This value is given to it also in it's constructor (`public Ship (int type)`).
Inside the constructor of `Ship`, Eclipse told me to call the superclass' constructor (aka `super()` - Don't know why I have to do that). So I call `super(type)` from within `Ship`'s constructor.

Aka:

```
public class Ship extends Entity{

    public Ship(int type){
        super(type);
    }

}

public class Entity{

    public Entity(int type){
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

Later, when I check the value in `type` for an instance of `Ship`, I always get a 0, no matter what value was put in the constructor when the instance was built.

I guess that I'm supposed to do `this.type = type` inside `Ship`'s constructor. But then, what's the point of inheritance? Isn't that supposed to take care of it?

Thanks

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis When Eclipse told me to call the superclass' constructor from within the subclass' constructor, it gave me inside the brackets the names of the 4 variables in `Entity`'s constructor. So super() must be referring to `Entity`, not to `Object`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How is it not fine?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ohhhh, sorry, my bad. Please see my edites question, changes one line of code in Entity.

Comment: You've changed the question into something quite different.  What do you get a `0` with?  What variable?  Did you include an instance variable `type` in `Entity` that you didn't show?

Comment: @user3150201 you need to define `type` within `Entity`

Comment: When I try to get the type value from a Ship entity, I always get a 0.

Comment: @user3150201 that can only happen if you shadow an original `type`, do you have `type` defined in the class `Ship` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion with the OP (see below), we've established that the actual problem was that there was a field named `type` in `Ship`, which was blocking visibility of the identically-named field in `Entity`. The obvious solution was to remove this field from `Ship`, allowing the superclass's field to be inherited as intended.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't

Comment: "It doesn't" -- Please specify. What "doesn't work"? What error message are you getting, where?

Comment: Ohhhh, sorry, my bad. Please see my edites question, changed one line of code in Entity.

Comment: Again: This should work, unless something you haven't shown us is overwriting `type` or unless Ship also declares variable named `type` which would block direct visibility of the one in Entity.

Comment: Oh - yes! That's it :) I had a variable named type both in Entity and in Ship. Deleted the one in Ship, and it works :) Please edit your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @user3150201 While it is appreciated that you (I'm guessing) reduced your code to try and keep your example short and concise, perhaps next time just copy + paste the relevant part without altering it. That way we can examine and catch things like that more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `super(type)` is a way of explicitly calling a superclass constructor that takes an argument.  That is valid for your `Ship` class, calling the `Entity` constructor with the argument.

But `Entity`'s superclass is `Object` (implicitly), and `Object` has a no-argument constructor, so there's no need to `super()` explicitly.  In a constructor, Java automatically inserts a call to the no-arg superclass constructor if `super()` isn't present.

Also, `Entity` is the place that you actually need to process the argument.  There's no need to pass `type` to `Object`, anyway.

Try

```
private int type;
public Entity(int type){
    this.type = type;
}
```

Handle the argument here in `Entity`, plus there's no need to call a superclass constructor explicitly.

Additionally, you may want to add a `public` getter method in `Entity` so that subclasses and other classes can access the `type` value.

Comment: Ohhhh, sorry, my bad. Please see my edited question, changed one line of code in Entity.

Answer (score 0):

My friend in entity class you not have any default constructor by default the compiler sees you code like

```
public class Ship extends Entity{

    public Ship(int type){
        super();   ------> added by compiler by default
    }

}
```

if u not added call to the super it will added default call to super that's the reason of error, so you have to add super(type); in first line of derived class constructor because you have only parameter constructor.

Comment: @user3150201, is it looks good to you what i explain my friend

Comment: @user3150201, if you need still more explanation please replied me